# MSi packages are getting uninstalled during repair

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

Inserted a checkbox in burn UI which sets a variable and works as a condition element for InstallCondition. It's working fine by installing those particular packages which are checked. But during repair this condition is becoming false and instead of reinstalling the packages it is uninstalling them. Here is the way how I used, Component_1 is the variable set by checkbox.

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="DevKit.msi"
                Vital="no"
                Compressed="yes"
                InstallCondition="Component_1"
                Visible="yes"/>
```

I need a proper way for InstallCondition which works fine during install, repair and uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

The condition isn't becoming false when you run in repair mode. Rather, it is not being set to anything which is then interpreted as failing the InstallCondition.

You will need to implement a method for 'remembering' whether or not the product was installed.

You can do this the permanent way which requires you to modify your bootstrapper application code or you can do it the explicit way which is much easier to implement.

The explicit way just sets the Component_1 property on a "exists" registry search.

Your DevKit.msi installer should write some sort of registry entries to indicate it is installed. You can do a registry search on this known registry entry to get the default value of Component_1

```
<util:RegistrySearch
  Id="DevKitInstalled"
  Root="HKLM"
  Key="SOFTWARE\DevKit"
  Format="raw"
  Value="Installed"
  Result="exists"
  Variable="Component_1"/>
```

You might have to make your InstallCondition `Component_1 = 1` but I'm not quite sure about this.

The more permanent fix for this is to edit OnDetectPackageComplete to set the related condition variable to 1. I would suggest you give all your msi packages an Id and use Properties with the same name as the Id so that you then know that if there is a variable with the same name as PackageId pass in from OnDetectPackageComplete, that you should set it to 1.

There might also be even better solutions, maybe someone else can give insight in a different answer =]